# Why can't Spyder open the Dictionary variable when I click on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, spyder

I create my dictionary through the following class, that at the end I believe is an ordinary dictionary subclass.

```
class my_dictionary(dict):
    # Function to add key:value 
    def add(self, key, value): 
        self[key] = value
```

I use this dictionary subclass to associate a list to a string:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

timeDict = my_dictionary()

filename = 'name'
t = [0, 1, 2]

timeDict.add(filename, t)
```

The code creates the dictionary and uses it as expected:

[image]

However, I can not inspect the dictionary in Spyder by clicking on it in variable explorer! I get the following error dialog:

> Error
>
> Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console.
>
> The error message was:
>
> *AttributeError("Can't get attribute 'my_dictionary' on ",)*

[image: error message]

Comment: `self = dict()` seems like a really strange thing to do.

Comment: I don't know if it's strange or not. I found the code and using it, it worked. There was a minor problem that I asked here. Do you have some guesses why it happens?. I don't know what the negative votes are for

Comment: I'm not sure either. I'm not that familiar with spyder, but I can tell you that you can remove the `__init__` method entirely without changing the functionality.

Comment: I removed that, but the negative vote is still there

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine. It's probably just someone who took a cursory look and clicked. That happens a lot, and people usually won't return to fix it. It has nothing to do with you, if that helps. Just ignore it as noise.

Comment: What did you have trouble finding on the internet? I found your exact issue, already reported: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8856

Comment: If you read through the comments, the developers are basically saying "wait"

Comment: yes true, since I was searching it with keyword dictionary , it did not come up for me ,but thank you

Comment: I edited your question to transcribe the error message. Could you check to make sure I got it right?

Comment: Yes Robert ! you did ! thank you

Comment: @RobertColumbia do you think there is still a problem or lack with the question ? cause I got a new downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in spyder: [#8856](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8856). The fix for it is under development for Spyder 4.0, according to the developers.

In the meantime, your particular use-case has a workaround. The `add` method does not add any new functionality, so you can use a plain `dict`. The statement `timeDict.add(filename, t)` can be replaced by `timeDict[filename] = t` if you choose to do that.

If your goal is to experiment with overriding built it classes, you will not be able to use Spyder's variable explorer for now.